# Access field in message inside a message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo

Being new to ros, I´ve stumbled into a stupid problem..

Im writing a python listener, and I want to get the orientation from an Imu.

The variable I want to access can be echoed with : rostopic echo /imu/orientation/z

Here is what I have so far - which is not really working out...:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu
from geometry_msgs.msg import Quaternion
def imu_callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo(Imu.orientation.z)
   #do something with z

def imu_listener():
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("imu", Imu, imu_callback)
    rospy.spin()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    imu_listener()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221451/access-field-in-message-inside-a-message/) by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `imu_callback` try

```
rospy.loginfo(data.orientation.z)
```

You need to use the message *variable* passed into your callback function (which you have named `data`), not the message *type*.

Be careful though, the orientation is represented as a quaternion, so if you are thinking that the `z` component is yaw you are going to have issues. See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/69754/quaternion-transformations-in-python/) for ways to convert rotations in rospy.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oevli](https://answers.ros.org/users/25151/oevli/) on 2015-11-24**:
Thanks :-)